# Sonarqube and Formal Methods

Tags: sonarqube, formal-methods

I've been reading about SonarQube source code analysis platform and I've been wondering: what about formal methods?

I see that tools such as [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) and [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) can be easily integrate since it's architecture promotes the use of plugins. Yet, I do not see abstract interpretation-based analyzers or even anything mentioning formal methods based tools.

I'm wondering if this is related with limitations with the rule-based approach of integrating plugins?

I read that [they are improving the semantic analysis of Java](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-java-analyzer-the-only-rule-engine-you-need/), perhaps this can enable formal methods-based approaches...

Anyone has more information on that? Like, if there is any interest in pursing in this direction from the SonarQube team?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, as I am the one who wrote the blog post you link I would like to answer but I am really not sure about what you are asking in fact. 
What would you want to achieve  (and more precisely, in which language, I assume Java) ? I have no deep knowledge of formal method approach so I would reformulate my question : What are the tools that you would need to achieve your goal and you are missing right now ? Then I can answer about our plans.

Comment: @benzonico, not necessarily just for Java, but for all languages (or for a subset of them. Alternatively, one could try to have some intermediary format, and the analyses could be run against this format..). <br/>Anyway, what I meant was that since I do not see anything related with this subject if that was due to some current limitation or simply lack of interest?

Comment: From the top of my head, some formal methods tools that could be interesting: [Astrée](http://www.absint.com/astree/index.htm), [PVS-Studio](http://www.viva64.com/en/pvs-studio/), or [QA-C++](http://www.programmingresearch.com/products/qacpp/) that actually includes the [Yices SMT solver](http://yices.csl.sri.com/)..

Comment: If you want to use an external tool to do some formal method analysis and report it in SQ, this is definitely doable, but afaik this is not something we have in mind, mainly because we want to improve or own analysers rather than focusing on integrating other ones. 
This said:  We are working on some approaches inside the java and C++ (commercial) plugin that somehow intersect with formal method approach.

Comment: SO is not the best place to have this conversation, feel free to reach our mailing list to discuss those matters.

Comment: @benzonico have there been any plugins developed for SonarQube that execute any formal methods / abstract interpretation, that you know of?